# "North Building" or "the North Building"?

Tags: definite-articles, proper-nouns

Our company has two buildings and they are referred to in internal communications in various forms. e.g., "the north building", "the North building" and "the North Building". I am aware that "north" as a direction is not capitalised. In our case the building names are North Building and South Building so both words should be capitalised.

Should the definite article be dropped? e.g., "Please proceed to North Building." vs. "Please proceed to the North Building."

Any examples?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single correct answer, but conventionally the definite article is more likely to be used when the word "Building" is part of the name of the building:

> Go to the Baxter Building

vs.

> Go to Carnegie Hall

Comment: And ... *"Now they know how many holes it takes to fill **the** Albert Hall."*